# I would like to use transitionFromView to flip in a new view and have my uiswitch that is on the second page, already be set, is this possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, transition, uiswitch

Edit: just to be clearer on what I am looking to do. I have 1 view with button on it. When you press the button a new view transisions in with a flip. On the new view their are two switched that I set through code after the user has clicked the button. What I want to happen is that the switches are in their final spots, before the new view flips in. What happens is the new view flips in, and then the UIswitches flicker into place.

This is the code I have. I have tried setting the uiswitch on viewwillappear and viewdidload, but each time it comes over with the default setting from IB and switched after the UIview transition is complete. I want the switch to be set already, so that once the view "flip" is done, there is no more movement on the screen. Thanks.

//set the uiswitch before the transision
 [self.settingsPage.myUISwitchThing setOn:NO animated:NO];

//transition by flip

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.settingsPage.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL done ) {
                [self.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Why was this voted down? If the question is not clear, let me know and I can rephrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that I was trying to animate the switch movement when I was setting the switch value in the viewdidload. setting  animated:NO has resolved the issue in the iPhone simulator. hopefully it will fix it on the device when I can test it at home later.